# Кнопка класса QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt

Создал класс кнопки, соответственно унаследовал от

```
QPushButton
```

но кнопка какая то странная, видно на скриншоте:

[image: Вывод]

Сам код:

```
EnterButton::EnterButton(QPushButton *parrent) : QPushButton(parrent)
{
    QPushButton*            enter = new QPushButton("");
    QPixmap                 pixButton(":/img/Images/button.png");
    QVBoxLayout*            qvbxLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    enter->setIcon(pixButton);
    enter->setIconSize(pixButton.size());

    qvbxLayout->addStretch(4);
    qvbxLayout->addWidget(enter);
    qvbxLayout->addStretch(4);

    setLayout(qvbxLayout);
}
```

Планировалось что в место стандартной кнопки будет изображение.

Comment: Если единственное, что нужно это изображение вместо кнопки, то зачем создавать свой класс? У стандартной кнопки уже есть метод для задания изображения кнопке.

Comment: Нет, это не единственное, потому что и без изображения кнопка имеет такой же вид.

Comment: Какие стили применены к кнопке? Что передаете в parent? Пишется с одной r

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю, но в конструкторе своей кнопки EnterButton вы создаете обычную кнопку QPushButton, т.е. у вас получается 2 кнопки. первая - это собственно ваша кнопка EnterButton, в которой внутри (т.е. как child) создан обычный QPushButton, из-за этого у вас всё так и выглядит.

Comment: То есть получается типа кнопка в кнопке?

Comment: Если вы хотите сделать кнопку-картинку, то нет необходимости в дополнительном QPushButton, её можно просто выкинуть и менять картинку прямо в "своей" кнопке, лэйаут тоже не нужен. Если же вы хотите создать комбинированный контрол (типа кнопка с картинкой и кнопкой), то в качестве класса родителя надо использовать QFrame или QWidget и уже внутри них выстраивать box-модель

Comment: @АндрейСаламов, да. Кнопка, в которой лэйаут, в котором кнопка, в которой картинка :)

Comment: Это уже понял)) сейчас буду разбираться.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Получилось разобраться с данной задачей так:

```
EnterButton::EnterButton(QPushButton *parent) : QPushButton(parent)
{
    QPixmap pixButton(":/img/Images/button.png");
    setIcon(pixButton);
    setIconSize(pixButton.size());
}
```